# c++ error: invalid use of non-static member function sprintf

Tags: c++, printf, arduino-uno

I have a simple class with various static elements. As long as I DO NOT call sprintf all compiles well. When sprintf is included (next to last line) the non-static member error occurs.

This is my first foray into c++; The other 500 lines of code clean compile. I have several classes with static elements.

Not sure how to clean this up.

```
class RTCClock {
private:
    static unsigned long lastMillisCheck;
    static RTC_DS1307 rtc;
    const char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    static bool isInitialized(bool setInitialized) {
        bool isInitialized = true;
        int initAddress = 55;  // use last vram entry
        int initializedValue = 0xAF;
        int initState = rtc.readnvram(initAddress);
        if (initState != initializedValue) {
            if (setInitialized) {
                rtc.writenvram(initAddress, initializedValue);
                rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
            }
            else {
                isInitialized = false;
            }
        }
        return isInitialized;
    }
public:
    static void Init() {
        isInitialized(true);
    }
    static char* GetDateTime() {
        char dtString[16];
        DateTime dt = rtc.now();
        char prototype[] = "%d/%d-%d:%d:%d";
        sprintf(dtString, prototype, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second);
        return dtString;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] (e.g. with proper includes)?

Comment: What's the full compiler output (error messages, line numbers, etc)?

Comment: Your function is broken anyway. It tries to return the address of a local variable (which promptly stops existing once the function returns).

Comment: Have you declared your static members? Aka: `unsigned long RTCClock::lastMillisCheck;` exists in a .cpp file somewhere? That's only a shot in the dark until you provide further data. And I am ignoring the other problems...

Comment: maybe try `std::sprintf` instead ? Without actual compilable code or the full compiler error, it's hard to say more...

Comment: There is no non-static `sprintf()` member in the class shown, so I see no way you can get such an error. Also, why bother with `sprintf()` at all? C++ is not C. Use `std::ostringstream` and `std::string` instead: `static std::string GetDateTime() { DateTime dt = rtc.now(); std::ostringstream oss; oss << dt.month << "/" << dt.day << "-" << dt.hour << ":" << dt.minute << ":" << dt.second; return oss.str(); }`